# Android-Out Of Memory Exception For ArrayList<Sting>

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, arraylist, out-of-memory

My code was running fine before I put few if else conditions.
I think there is optimization issues in for loop but not getting it

```
     btSetQuantity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (etbillQuantity.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Quantity Not Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                                    etbillQuantity.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                        } else if (Double.parseDouble(etbillQuantity.getText()
                                .toString()) > initialQuantityValue) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Short Of Quantity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();

                        } else {

                            strEnteredQuantity = etbillQuantity.getText()
                                    .toString();

                            enteredQuantityValue = Double
                                    .parseDouble(strEnteredQuantity);

                            tempproduct_TotalQuantity.add(tvInitialQuantity
                                    .getText().toString());

                            newQuantityValue = initialQuantityValue
                                    - enteredQuantityValue;

                            setQuantity.setText(strEnteredQuantity);
                            String setQuantityStr = "";

                            GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductSetQuantity
                                    .add(strEnteredQuantity);
                            GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductName.add(tvName
                                    .getText().toString());
                            GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductCode.add(tvCode
                                    .getText().toString());
                            GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductUnitPrice
                                    .add(tvPrice.getText().toString());
                            GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductQuantity
                                    .add((String.valueOf(newQuantityValue)));

                            if (tempproduct_Code.size() <= 0) {
                                tempproduct_Code.add(tvCode.getText()
                                        .toString());
                                tempproduct_Name.add(tvName.getText()
                                        .toString());
                                tempproduct_Quantity.add(strEnteredQuantity);
                                tempproduct_UnitPrice.add(tvPrice.getText()
                                        .toString());
                            }

                            else {
                                String setQuantityTemp = "";
                                String setUnitPriceTemp = "";
                                String setNameTemp = "";
                                String setCodeTemp = "";

                                for (int i = 0; i < (tempproduct_Code.size()); i++) {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < (GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductCode
                                            .size()); j++) {

                                        if (tempproduct_Code
                                                .get(i)
                                                .contains(
                                                        GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductCode
                                                                .get(j))) {
                                            setQuantityTemp = GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductSetQuantity
                                                    .get(j);
                                            tempproduct_Quantity.set(i,
                                                    setQuantityTemp);

                                            setCodeTemp = GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductCode
                                                    .get(j);
                                            tempproduct_Code
                                                    .set(i, setCodeTemp);
                                            setNameTemp = GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductName
                                                    .get(j);
                                            tempproduct_Name
                                                    .set(i, setNameTemp);
                                            setUnitPriceTemp = GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductUnitPrice
                                                    .get(j);
                                            tempproduct_UnitPrice.set(i,
                                                    setUnitPriceTemp);

                                        } else {
                                            tempproduct_Code.add(tvCode
                                                    .getText().toString());
                                            tempproduct_Name.add(tvName
                                                    .getText().toString());
                                            tempproduct_Quantity
                                                    .add(strEnteredQuantity);
                                            tempproduct_UnitPrice.add(tvPrice
                                                    .getText().toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                                    etbillQuantity.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            onSetQuantityDisplayData();
                            alertDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    }
                    });
```

It's now showing Out Of Memory in log 
I have used best way possible for list views performance optimization
log showing out of memory on arraylist 
log also shows grow heap for some time app is struct and crashes

```
04-24 12:31:27.463: I/dalvikvm-heap(1136): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.725MB for 4021256-byte allocation
04-24 12:31:28.063: D/dalvikvm(1136): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2618K, 34% free 18530K/27816K, paused 536ms, total 536ms
04-24 12:31:28.063: I/dalvikvm-heap(1136): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.003MB for 4021256-byte allocation
04-24 12:31:37.813: D/dalvikvm(1136): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2618K, 29% free 19839K/27816K, paused 708ms, total 708ms
04-24 12:31:37.813: I/dalvikvm-heap(1136): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 6031876-byte allocation
04-24 12:31:38.553: D/dalvikvm(1136): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 29% free 19829K/27816K, paused 730ms, total 732ms

    04-24 12:31:38.553: E/dalvikvm-heap(1136): Out of memory on a 6031876-byte allocation.


04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853): Process: com.vardhan.android.navigationdrawerexample, PID: 2853
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at com.vardhan.android.navigationdrawerexample.BillingProductListView$1$13.onClick(BillingProductListView.java:349)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-24 08:56:04.143: E/AndroidRuntime(2853):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Skynet done please Check

Comment: What is the line 349, please mark it here? Does the error always occur at this particular line?

Comment: @Skynet tempproduct_Code.add(tvCode.getText().toString());  dont know how to mark please help

Comment: How do you define `tempproduct_Code`

Comment: @Skynet private ArrayList<String> tempproduct_Code = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Try to change if (tempproduct_Code.size() <= 0) to  if (tempproduct_Code.size() >= 0)

Comment: @Sidd no i want that block to execute when tempproduct_Code.size() is 0....error is ocuuring at tempproduct_Code.add(tvCode=.getText().toString()); which is in else block at line 20 from down...not in top section...please help

Comment: you create a 6Mb object...

Comment: @BhushanChichani, see my answer please. Its occurring due to infinite loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here, due to your logical mistake , the outer loop has become an infinite loop.

```
  else {
// YOUR OTHER CODES

        for (int i = 0; i < (tempproduct_Code.size()); i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < (GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductCode                                                    .size()); j++) {

             if (tempproduct_Code.get(i).contains(GlobalVariables.arrayOfTempProductCode
                                                                    .get(j))) {
                  // your other codes

               } else {
                   tempproduct_Code.add(tvCode.getText().toString()); // here you are continuously increasing your tempproduct_Code's size and your outer loops condition is also depending on the same size. thus your loop is running & ultimately leading you to OutOfMemory error
                   tempproduct_Name.add(tvName.getText().toString());
                   tempproduct_Quantity.add(strEnteredQuantity);
                   tempproduct_UnitPrice.add(tvPrice.getText().toString());
              }
       }
 }
```

So your code has become like **a dog is chasing it's own tail.** check your business requirements & modify your logic

Comment: Thank you so much, this had me going for days.